# Html searchbox open page with keyword

Tags: html, css, search, keyword

Is it possible to make a search box using HTML, CSS and JavaScript that opens a page based on the keyword the user types in the page the file needs to open is stored on the computer for example `C:\example\folder\file.html`

Comment: yes you can do. But you may need little PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
 <input type="file">
```

After selecting file get the path of the file and then open the file using PHP

```
<?php
$myfile = fopen($filepath, "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
echo fread($myfile,filesize($filepath));
fclose($myfile);
?>
```

As your path is not fixed you need to store the file at some directory which is fixed after uploading.